# Pass class type in databinding attribute

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-binding-adapter

Can we do something like this in android databinding

```
itemType="@{MyClass::class}"
```

For binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["itemType"])
fun <T> func(
view: View,
itemType: Class<T>,
) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you wouldn't pass class, rather you would pass data object. Here is the example:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/bookList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:items="@{viewmodel.items}" />
```

And here is the Binding Adapter for this:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:items")
@JvmStatic
fun setItems(listView: ListView, items: List<Book>) {
    with(listView.adapter as BookListAdapter) {
        replaceData(items)
    }
}
```

Given that `viewmodel.items` is LiveData, updating it will automatically update listview.